# Oracle SQL Function selecting output

Tags: oracle, function, return-value

I am not so used to pipelined functions in Oracle. I worked a lot with Sybase, and MS SQL Server, but Oracle is more or less new to me.

I am using a function from a colleague who left a while ago.
This function return something, if I am not totally wrong:

```
return ty_CouponTypes_tab pipelined is
V_CT varchar(3);
V_PST varchar(5);
```

I created a view and iterate over this view with a cursor and pass all the columns to the function, but how can I get the result of this function?
This is what I do not understand.

This is my cursor

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
declare
cursor cCur is select * from VW_PRE_WHITELIST;
begin
for vCurData in cCur
loop
dbms_output.put_line(vCurData.MAT_NAME || ' ' || vCurData.DST_SKONTRO || ' '     || vCurData.DST_ZINSART || ' ' || vCurData.UND_TYP || ' ' || vCurData.DZU_RZ_ERWARTET || ' ' || vCurData.DST_ERSTZINS || ' ' || vCurData.CNT);
select a.* FROM FN_COUPONTYPES(vCurData.MAT_NAME, vCurData.DST_SKONTRO,     vCurData.DST_ZINSART, vCurData.UND_TYP, vCurData.DZU_RZ_ERWARTET, vCurData.DST_ERSTZINS, vCurData.CNT) a;
end loop;
end;
```

Thanks for helping me in advance!

Comment: `how can I get the result of this function?` By using `table()` operator as in `select * from table(FN_COUPONTYPES(...))`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is it what I was looking for.